# jQuery ajaxStart with php code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am reading about Ajax Events from the jQuery [docs](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ajax-events/).

My jQuery code with some HTML:

```
<p style="display:none">Loading...</p>
<div></div>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("p")
    .ajaxStart(function(){
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });


    $.ajax({

        url :    'http://localhost/xampp/web_development/new_study_2014/my_files/test.php',
        data :   {id : 123},
        type :    "GET",
        dataType : "html",
        success: function(response) {
            $("div").hide().html(response).fadeIn(1500);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            console.log( xhr + status + errorThrown );
        },
        complete: function() {
            console.log(  );
        }
    });

});
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
sleep(1);
echo "<p> his name is jack</p>";
?>
```

I wanted the paragraph that says `Loading...` to display when the ajax request starts and hides when it is finished. As described in the jQuery docs. Yet it does none of the two and displays "his name is jack" from the php page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/): As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target of the `ajaxStart` event is the document, not a particular element, so using `$(this)` in the handler won't work. Change it to select the specific element.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#loading").show();
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $("#loading").hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
<p id="loading" style="display: none;">Loading...</p>
```

Comment: Thanks did it as you specified but still same output as the above question.

Comment: If you put `alert()` into the `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` functions, do they fire?

Comment: Hmm that's weird. It does `alert()`  for both start and stop but for some reason the show and hide of the paragraph does not work. The code I posted is pretty straightforward.

Comment: It works on jsfiddle but not locally. Locally it now shows `Loading...` for like a microsecond and then disappears.